# How do I pass variables that are set in the parent class to child class?

Tags: php, oop

```
class a
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->id = 123;
    }
}

class b extends a
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo parent::id;
    }
}
```

How do I pass variables that are set in the first class $this to the second class?

Comment: you may not able to use `parent::id;` in this case since its not a static property in the parent class.

Answer (score 5):

The correct way is to simply use `$this->id` in your subclass. All public/protected variables are available to subclasses this way. By assigning `$this->id` without declaring it, you've implicitly made it public. Generally you should explicitly declare the variable in the base class to document your intent to make it public:

```
class a
{
    public $id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->id = 123;
    }
}
```

Just remember to call `parent::__construct()` before you attempt to access members set by the parent class. Unlike some languages (C++) the parent class's constructor will not be automatically invoked for you.

```
class b extends a
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        echo $this->id;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 nice to have same idea like someone more experienced, and... faster :)

Comment: @Matthew There is no reason *not* to make it public; access specifies were not the subject of the question.

Comment: The reason is the same as always, don't make accessibility broader than necessary.  There is no indication the `id` is needed outside the class.  I didn't claim that was the main question.

Comment: @Matthew I would consider that quite tangential; I could also have given the classes better names and defined getter/setter methods, as long as we are going out of our way to write a "correct" *8 line snippet*. This would in no way have made the answer clearer for the novice asking the question.

Comment: @meagar, you didn't introduce the class names, but you're the one adding the field declaration.  *Because* he's a novice (and likely somewhat unfamiliar with access specifiers), it's useful to clarify that only `protected` is needed.

Comment: @Matthew That would necessarily introduce at least a paragraph on access specifiers, outside the scope of this question.

Comment: @meagar, I disagree.  You didn't explain `public`; who said you have to explain `protected`?  He can find details on either by searching or browsing PHP.net.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `parent::__construct()` to get things that are initialized in the parent class. If you don't have anything to initialize in the child class you can avoid `__construct()` in the child class and it will automatically take the parent construct.